# Missing JSON Data

Tags: java, json, hibernate, playframework, jackson

I use Jackson to serialize my model classes. I serialize a List of Project Objects. Each Project Object should contain the user Data of its creator but i only get the data for the first Entry in the List. For all the other Projects I only get the id of the creator.

Why is the data not included for all Projects?

```
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "TESTPROJEKT 2",
      "creator": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin",
        ....
      },
      ...
    },
    {
      "name": "TESTPROJEKT 3",
      "creator": 1,
      ...
    },
    ...
```

Project.java model class

```
@Entity
public class Project {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "creator")
private Usr creator;
...
```

I call the serialization witn `Json.toJson(projects)` with projects being a `List<Projects>` containing all data. The debugger says the data is in the List before the Serialization.

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the `Usr` object look like?  If the `creator` is the same for multiple `Project`, Jackson may not attempt to de-serialize it twice into it's full object.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117097/1956540