# Spring (Hibernate) - incomplete serialization result / many-to-many

Tags: spring, hibernate, serialization, jackson, many-to-many

Rest Application / Spring MVC - 3 entities:  User, AccessRole, AccessPermision.
Each user has only one role, each role has one or more privileges.
The problem occurs during serialization of users with the same role.
In such case, the JSON serialization result, contains permissions only for the first user.

**User Entity**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import socialcreek.access.model.AccessRole;
import socialcreek.user.views.UserViews;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity 
@Table(name = "users")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")

public class User {

    /**-----------------------------------------------------
     * Constructor
     -------------------------------------------------------*/

    public User(){  }

    public User(String username, String password, AccessRole accessRole) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.userAccessRole = accessRole;
    }

    /**-----------------------------------------------------
     * Entity Properties
     -------------------------------------------------------*/

    @Column()
    @Id
    @JsonView(UserViews.BasicView.class)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(UserViews.BasicView.class)
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @JsonView(UserViews.BasicView.class)
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UsersGroup> usersGroups;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = AccessRole.class, optional = false,fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_role")
    @JsonView(UserViews.BasicView.class)
    private AccessRole userAccessRole;


    /**-----------------------------------------------------
     * Setters & Getters
     -------------------------------------------------------*/

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() { 
        return username; 
    } 

    public void setUsername(String username) { 
        this.username = username; 
    } 

    public String getPassword() { 
        return password; 
    } 

    public void setPassword(String password) { 
        this.password = password; 
    }

    public Set<UsersGroup> getUsersGroups() {
        return usersGroups;
    }

    public void setUsersGroups(Set<UsersGroup> usersGroups) {
        this.usersGroups = usersGroups;
    }

    public AccessRole getUserAccessRole() {
        return userAccessRole;
    }

    public void setUserAccessRole(AccessRole userAccessRole) {
        this.userAccessRole = userAccessRole;
    }
}
```

**AccessRole Entity**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import socialcreek.user.views.UserViews;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "access_role")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
public class AccessRole {


    /**-----------------------------------------------------
     * Entity Properties
     -------------------------------------------------------*/

    @Id
    @JsonView(UserViews.BasicView.class)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(UserViews.BasicView.class)
    private String roleName;

    @JsonView(UserViews.BasicView.class)
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "access_role_permissions")
    private Set<AccessPermission> accessPermissions;

    /**-----------------------------------------------------
     * Setters & Getters
     -------------------------------------------------------*/


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public Set<AccessPermission> getAccessPermissions() {
        return accessPermissions;
    }

    public void setAccessPermissions(Set<AccessPermission> accessPermissions) {
        this.accessPermissions = accessPermissions;
    }


}
```

**AccessPermission Entity**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import socialcreek.user.views.UserViews;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "access_permission")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
public class AccessPermission {

    /**-----------------------------------------------------
     * Entity Properties
     -------------------------------------------------------*/

    @Id
    @JsonView(UserViews.BasicView.class)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(UserViews.BasicView.class)
    private String permissionName;


    /**-----------------------------------------------------
     * Setters & Getters
     -------------------------------------------------------*/


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPermissionName() {
        return permissionName;
    }

    public void setPermissionName(String permissionName) {
        this.permissionName = permissionName;
    }

}
```

Serialization Result:

> [ { "id":70, "username":"admin", "usersGroups":[], "userAccessRole":{
>             "id":68,            "roleName":"ROLE_ADMIN",            "accessPermissions":[
>                 {
>                 "id":69,
>                 "permissionName":"FULL_ACCESS"
>                 }]} },
>   { "id":71, "username":"admin2", "usersGroups":[], "userAccessRole":68}
>   ]

Please, have a look at accessRole and accessPermision information - it's complete only for the user:admin. In case of user:admin2 there is only information about accessRoleId ( no information about roleName, accessPermision)
It happens only when both users have the same accessRole. If I change accessRole of user:admin2 to another role - everythnink will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found the similar issue with the correct answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117097/4694022).
The problem is caused by @JsonIdentityInfo. After I removed it - it works ...now I need to find the solution to handle serialization for recursive structure but it's another story ...